# AH01797: client denied by server configuration Wordpress Plugin JS Files in Apache Web server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, suexec

I am having problems while trying to add a post to a Wordpress website. This site works in schematic using fastcgi, inside a subdomain like email.medialab.ufg.br. The issues seem to be related to accessing .js and .css files from a Wordpress plugin. Here is the error reported:

```
[Fri Jun 08 13:45:44.000087 2018] [access_compat:error] [pid 32401] [client 200.137.195.149:63863] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /home/l3p/apache_sites/email.medialab.ufg.br/web/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro/assets/inc/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js, referer: https://email.medialab.ufg.br/wp-admin/post-new.php?gutenberg-demo
```

The site's .htaccess file has the following configuration:
**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And the virtualhost file the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

                                DocumentRoot /home/l3p/apache_sites/email.medialab.ufg.br/web

    ServerName email.medialab.ufg.br
    ServerAlias www.email.medialab.ufg.br
    ServerAdmin webmaster@email.medialab.ufg.br

    ErrorLog /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/email.medialab.ufg.br/error.log

    Alias /error/ "/home/l3p/apache_sites/email.medialab.ufg.br/web/error/"
    ErrorDocument 400 /error/400.html
    ErrorDocument 401 /error/401.html
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.html
    ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
    ErrorDocument 405 /error/405.html
    ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.html
    ErrorDocument 502 /error/502.html
    ErrorDocument 503 /error/503.html


    <Directory /home/l3p/apache_sites/email.medialab.ufg.br/web>
            # Clear PHP settings of this website
            <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
                    SetHandler None
            </FilesMatch>
            Options +FollowSymLinks  +Indexes +Multiviews
            AllowOverride All
                            Require all granted
                    </Directory>







    <Directory /home/l3p/apache_sites/clients/client1/web73/web>
            # Clear PHP settings of this website
            <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
                    SetHandler None
            </FilesMatch>
            Options +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
                            Require all granted
                    </Directory>




    # suexec enabled
    <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
        SuexecUserGroup web73 client1
    </IfModule>
    # php as fast-cgi enabled
# For config options see: http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html
    <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
            FcgidIdleTimeout 300
            FcgidProcessLifeTime 3600
            # FcgidMaxProcesses 1000
            FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 5000
            FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
            FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 10
            FcgidConnectTimeout 3
            FcgidIOTimeout 600
            FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
            FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
    </IfModule>
    <Directory /home/l3p/apache_sites/email.medialab.ufg.br/web>
            <FilesMatch "\.php[345]?$">
                SetHandler fcgid-script
            </FilesMatch>
            FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web73/.php-fcgi-starter .php
            FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web73/.php-fcgi-starter .php3
            FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web73/.php-fcgi-starter .php4
            FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web73/.php-fcgi-starter .php5
            Options +ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
                            Require all granted
                    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/l3p/apache_sites/clients/client1/web73/web>
            <FilesMatch "\.php[345]?$">
                SetHandler fcgid-script
            </FilesMatch>
            FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web73/.php-fcgi-starter .php
            FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web73/.php-fcgi-starter .php3
            FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web73/.php-fcgi-starter .php4
            FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web73/.php-fcgi-starter .php5
            Options +ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
                            Require all granted
                    </Directory>




    # add support for apache mpm_itk
    <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
        AssignUserId web73 client1
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
    # Do not execute PHP files in webdav directory
        <Directory /home/l3p/apache_sites/clients/client1/web73/webdav>
            <ifModule mod_security2.c>
                SecRuleRemoveById 960015
                SecRuleRemoveById 960032
            </ifModule>
            <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
                SetHandler None
            </FilesMatch>
        </Directory>
        DavLockDB /home/l3p/apache_sites/clients/client1/web73/tmp/DavLock
        # DO NOT REMOVE THE COMMENTS!
        # IF YOU REMOVE THEM, WEBDAV WILL NOT WORK ANYMORE!
  # WEBDAV BEGIN
        # WEBDAV END
    </IfModule>
```

Any idea what might be going on?
How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking for more information in your logs. I had a similar issue. When I just searched for the 503 error, I only got the error message you have. When I looked at messages around it, I saw:

```
mod_lsapi: [host <domain_name>] [req GET / HTTP/1.1]
    Could not connect to lsphp backend: connect to lsphp failed: 110
```

My server uses cPanel for management. Going into cpanel and manually selecting the PHP version fixed this. I'm not sure the same will be true for you, but the error messages might help you narrow in on the problem.